# Servers on the same network aren't communicating

Tags: networking

A number of servers are connected to WAN via a switch. Each server has it's own static public IP assigned by the ISP. Gateway on the server is the same. No firewalls.

The following is an example of ping command from one of the server, pinging another server that sits next to it:

```
PING 188.199.17.12 (188.199.17.12) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 188.199.17.12 ping statistics ---
217 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 215884ms
```

How can communication between the servers be achieved?

Comment: It is likely that the server firewalls are set to block ICMP. That doesn't mean the servers cannot communicate, only that you can't use ICMP (ping) between them.

Comment: Can not SSH, send UDP or establish any sort of communication.

Comment: Do you have the right subnet mask configured on both servers? And are these two physical servers?

Comment: Only two things can be wrong as already suggested. Either you've got a firewall turned on at one or both servers, or you have the subnet mask programmed in wrong. You should double check with your ISP what the proper network settings are supposed to be.

Comment: After trying to reach server B from server A, can you see server B's MAC address on the ARP table of server A?  The switch may be configured to avoid any routing, and may even block ARP traffic whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that the "WAN Switch" is configured in "Secure Mode", which is Cisco speak for not allowing communication between the ports (only to the upstream port where your WAN router(s) are).

In that case it might be intentional (for security-, traffic minimization- or accounting reasons) or by accident (missing network route) that the servers can't speak to each other.

You would have to talk to the owner of the WAN Switch or setup a second network between the servers with your own equipment.

Not seeing any of the resolved MAC addresses in the neighbour cache of a server besides the gateway is a good indication for that, as suggested by some comments.

Answer (score 1):

Check the local ARP table. If you've got the destination server's MAC address in it all is well. It's just the firewall that filtering your requests and eating up the pings.